above continuity of an additive function over an algebra at the empty set implies is it bellow continuous
given a set $\Omega$ and a function $\mu: \mathscr{C} \mapsto \mathbb{R}_+\cup\{+\infty\}$
where $\mathscr{C} \subseteq \mathcal{P} (\mathbb{\Omega})$ is an algebra and $\mu$ is additive
trying to prove: $\mu$ continuous from above at $\varnothing$ $\implies$ $\mu$ continuous from below
given:
$(E_n)\rightarrow E$ where $\forall n\in \mathbb{N} \quad E_n\subseteq E_{n+1}$ and $E_n,E \in \mathscr{C}$
we get $(E-E_n)\rightarrow \varnothing$
so then (because $\mu$ is continuous from above at $\varnothing$)
$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}\mu(E-E_n) = \mu(\varnothing) = 0$$
$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}\mu(E)-\mu(E_n) = 0$$
$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}\mu(E_n) = \mu(E)$$
i dont know where the error is in the proof

You can't write $\mu(E)-\mu(E_n)$ if both $\mu(E)$ and $\mu(E_n)$ are infinite.
